# Determine Start of Download

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I am looking to determine that a download has begun, preferably with jQuery.

I am serving up dynamically created downloads that take 5-10 seconds to create. I would like to use JavaScript to post a message to the browser that the file is being created, and remove that message once creation is complete and the download begins.

Posting the message is easy. I can do that when the user clicks the link. I just can't find a way to remove the message when it is no longer needed.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe using something here http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/progress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could provide the download through a script for example download.php?file=image.jpg

When someone accesses it and the script starts to send the file, you could log this in a database.

Your site could then make an ajax call to an other script which tells whether the download has started or not, by looking in the database. If it started you can hide the message, if not make an other call a bit later.

Comment: The solution I implemented is close to this. Rather than saving the data to a database, I saved the download creation progress to a session cookie and accessed that information through a looping ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Totally different approach which avoids the ajax polling:

The http response of the download request sets a cookie which can be checked regularly on the page which provided the download link. This way you are only polling the browsers cookie storage and not your server.